# Operating Systems - Process

Tags: c

Considering this two programs:

```
 //in  
 #define MAX 50
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     int *count;
     int fd=shm_open("/count",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
     int ret=ftruncate(fd,sizeof(int));
     count=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);

     while ((*count)==MAX);
     (*count)++;
 }

  //out 
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      int *count;
      int fd=shm_open("/count",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
      int ret=ftruncate(fd,sizeof(int));

      count=mmap(0,sizeof(int),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);

      (*count)--;
 }
```

I have two questions:

1) Why this program doesn't work properly (doesn't ensure that the number of count never exceeds 50)?

2) How can I correct the two programs to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: First of, you should check the return values from the system calls. You don't really know if they succeed or not.

Comment: How can I ensure  that the number of count never exceeds 50?Thanks.

Comment: The control flow here is unclear. When do these 2 programs run? How many times does each of them run?

Comment: They don't a have a fixed number to run.

Answer (score 0):

You Sure you want to do :

```
while((*count)==MAX); // semicolon ?
```

instead of

```
    while(*count==MAX)
       (*count)++;
```

Also check the return value from mmap it might be failing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused regarding loops. The word "never" implies that you'd want an infinite loop, in this case. `while ((*count)==MAX)` is not an infinite loop. Inside the infinite loop, I presume you'd want logic that determines if *count is greater than 50, and acts from there. If you're struggling to express your algorithms in C, I would suggest reading a book such as K&R's "The C Programming Language". That book is most likely available in your native language.